# Why extracting POT file with CakePHP is blocked by exception "Cannot use 'DebugKit\Command\BenchmarkCommand'"?

Tags: internationalization, cakephp-4.x

Good morning,
I'm using CakePHP 4, I just tried to extract a POT file in order to translate my project using the command "bin/cake i18n extract" and I got the following error:

`Exception: Cannot use 'DebugKit\Command\BenchmarkCommand' for command 'benchmark'. It is not a subclass of Cake\Console\Shell or Cake\Command\Command. In [H:\wamp64\www\contest\adt-ardeche\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Console\CommandCollection.php, line 68]`

I don't understand why the "benchmark" command must be used at this time.

During my last uses, everything went well.

I haven't found anyone else having this problem.

Has anyone already obtained this result or have any ideas?

Thank you for your answers.

Sincerely,
Alexis